# Filter out null fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm using map/reduce functionality with the painless language to do some aggregation.

In the *map_script* part I am trying to filter out all documents that have a certain field set to *null* but I am unable to do so.

I've tried doing `containsKey()` and `!= null` but the expression evaluates to *true* for every document even though I've look at the underlying data and the vast majority of documents have this field set to *null*.

I can't explain this but it's behaving as this field's value for almost every document is treated as 0, not null, here when I'm aggregating it. But this is not the case because when I do query of this field, I see a bunch of nulls.

```json
{
    "aggs": {
        "my_agg_name": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "combine_script": "... combine script ...",
                "map_script": "if (doc.containsKey(\"my_field\") && doc.my_field.value != null) { ... } }",
                "init_script": "... init script ...",
                "reduce_script": "... reduce script ..."
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on? How to filter out nulls in the map/reduce aggregation using painless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. `doc.my_field.value` apparently transforms the null value into 0.

What worked is using `!doc.my_field.empty` instead.